# Confused about os module

Tags: python, operating-system

1. I am confused about os module

   I have learned that use **import** to import module.

We have file `os.py`.

Do we have file `os.path.py`?

2. `os.path.abspath()`

I have read the official Python document.
I did not fully understand what it meant.

I try `os.path.abspath("xxx")`
I found even the file did not exist, it still returns the path.

```
ex: os.path.abspath("fadsffefsfgg")

then return 

'C:\\Users\\user-t\\fadsffefsfgg'
```

Comment: What _exactly_ are you asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> os.path
<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\ntpath.py'>
```

so no, `os.path.py` doesn't exist. In `os` module there's probably something like:

```
import ntpath as path
```

now the path is `os.path`.

For your second question, `os.path.abspath` just prepends the current path to any path if it's not absolute.

It's not a file operation, it's a string operation. It doesn't even check if the file exists, and that's for the best: imagine that you want to *create* such a file...